# Is it appropriate for my use case?

Tags: drupal-8

I have a use case which requires following Customer Front End, and Back End (Leads Management, Pricing / RFQ ,Invoicing and Finance management, inventory management, , Supplier Management)

Is civicrm the right choice?

This question is related to drupal 8/9 and civicrm 5.37

Comment: You can use Activities to track things like Lead Mgmt, or CiviCase for more complex workflows but it is not primarily designed (imo) for those sort of commercial 'opportunities'

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks. Do you know of any other drupal crm modules as good as civicrm?

Comment: I have only used civicrm - for about 13 years on hundreds of projects - have always managed to bend it round to the shape i needed it, and could probably do so for what you are describing by using Activities as the primary entity. But I have never tried to do 'finance' mgmt, nor 'inventory' mgmt and really no idea what you actually mean by those v broad statements